# Migrate for Compute Engine not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy Migrate for Compute Engine (velostrata) from GCP Market place but I get this error "A required resource is not available." with a tracking number.
Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: The error occurred on Marketplace but later disappeared. It looks like it was a random hitch on the Google side. At the moment this deployment is available. You can remove this post.

Comment: This morning I checked the offering on Marketplace, and the error reappeared. So the question remains relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem appears randomly, and this is most likely a bug on the Google side.

Meanwhile, there is a newly created [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157216732) on the Issue Tracker. You may follow it.